# Spring Boot some path variable are missing but return 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am a beginner of boot . Code as below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/channel")

public class ChannelController 
{
    @GetMapping("/getId/{participantId}/{walletType}")
    Map<String,Object> getChannelId(@PathVariable Integer participantId , @PathVariable Integer walletType ){
        return demoDAOImpl.getChannel(participantId, walletType);
    }
}
```

When I hit `http://localhost:8080/channel/getId///`, it returns the default Whitelabel Error Page, which states

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Here I am confused. I thought Spring MVC should throw a `MissingPathVariableException`. Why is it responding with a 404 response, resource not found?

Comment: I am using boot 1.5.6 ,thx

Comment: What is this `PathVariableMissingException` you speak of? Why should that be thrown?

Comment: sorry for typo , MissingPathVariableException is a Spring build-in exception , "typically that means the URI template does not match the path variable name declared on the method parameter."(from Spring original comment).

Comment: `MissingPathVariableException` is thrown if you have a `@Path` variable with name `example`, but no `{example}` uri variable in the `@RequestMapping` path. _Typically that means the URI template does not match the path variable name declared on the method parameter._

Comment: Oh , this is the point I really don't know. Let me try it .

Comment: yes,finally figure it out , thx

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are asking for is to customized the exception. Then what you need is to provide a handler, you can just simply extend abstract class ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and override the method handleMissingPathVariable.

One example:

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingPathVariable(MissingPathVariableException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

    String error = ex.getParameter() + " parameter is missing";
    ErrorMessageHandler error =message(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.toString(), error) ;
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

}
```

Comment: This is actually proper answer I think. Is this the only way to convert MissingPathVariableException into 4XX error? Why Spring Boot doesn't do this automatically when @PathVariable is entity?

Comment: This is not working for Path variable missing :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@PathVariable(required = false)` and handle the logic manually:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/channel")
public class ChannelController 
{
    @GetMapping("/getId/{participantId}/{walletType}")
    Map<String,Object> getChannelId(@PathVariable(required = false) Integer participantId , @PathVariable(required = false) Integer walletType) {

        if (participantId == null) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Participant is required");
        }

        if (walletType == null) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Wallet type is required");
        }

        return demoDAOImpl.getChannel(participantId, walletType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `MissingPathVariableException` to be thrown, the request has to match a request mapping. To make your controller to handle the `http://localhost:8080/channel/getId///` request, you would need to declare your **GetMapping** annotation as follows:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"getId///", "/getId/{participantId}/{walletType}"})
```

Answer (score -2):

base on your url mapping: you can't leave it blank like "**///**" it must be "**/number/number/**"

i.e **http://localhost:8080/channel/getId/0/0/**

Comment: that is no problem, the problem is how to catch the exception path variable is missing to return friendly message to client?

Comment: so you should search for how to customize spring-boot 404 page

Comment: no ,  hope to catch path variable missing exception , then return some message to client, thx

Comment: this answer does not deserve minus merits . Also this answer should be just a comment which describes the issue but not answering the issue .