# empty path variable inside url get me 404 not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i have a request with empty path variable that get me a 404 response.how can i get my GET request to go into my webservice and throw exception showing that the pathvariable is empty. for now i'm having a 404 not found exception. exemple : GET 
request url : hello/123/me ==> works fine
request url hello//me ===> 404 not found

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/hello/{uuid}/me")
public ResponseEntity<Void> hello(
        @PathVariable(name = "uuid", required = false) String uuid){
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot some path variable are missing but return 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726148/spring-boot-some-path-variable-are-missing-but-return-404)

Comment: i already did the required false, also i didn't find a solution in the stack u refer too. thank u my friend. i can't create an entire handler juste for one ws

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with the following code.

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/hello/{uuid}/me", "/hello//me"})
public ResponseEntity<Void> hello(@PathVariable(name = "uuid", required = false) String uuid) {
```

What I have done is, just added /hello//me also to the request mapping of the same function. You can add multiple URLs just like this.

I suggest making the URL without parameters as /hello/me just to make it a standard, obviously if you have a scenario where you want to achieve it with /hello//me, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this the answer you looking for...., basically you want to pass the value of that **uuid** to be checked if its valid or not. If its not you can pass the exception into the web service using `IllegalStateException`. If you using **getter** and **setter** with **JPA** in your **spring** this can be done :

```
Optional<ClassName> validUuid = NameObjectofYourJPARepo.findByUuid(YourClassName.getUuid());

if(!validUuid.isPresent()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("404 not found");
}
```

I hope this can answer your problem

Comment: i already have that but i don't receive the request to add my custom exception in it. i have 404 not found. i don't understand what u mean by adding my own exception, are u saying to change my 404 exception ? no thats not what i'm looking for

Comment: Maybe I get the point, I hope this is can solve your problem. Just edited my answer @Abdel

Comment: i think u didn't get the problem i'm facing. thank u for your help anyway. the 404 is in my controller first. the problem is with spring normalization of the URL. i need to disable it to make it happen. i did a simple solution is by putting my uuid in last in my url and then using otpional parameter as a pathVariable which is not a good practice but it works